# Переопределение prototype конструктора

Tags: javascript

В процессе изучения основ js, наткнулся на проблему с пониманием одного момента в работе прототипного наследования. В примере ниже, в моём представлении, по итогу работы кода rabbit._ _proto__ должно ссылаться на Rabbit.prototype.

Последний же, в свою очередь должен равняться пустому объекту, так как (1). Но по факту, изменения в Rabbit.prototype по какой-то причине не заносятся.

```js
function Rabbit() {}
Rabbit.prototype = {
  eats: true
};

var rabbit = new Rabbit();

Rabbit.prototype = {}; (1)

console.log( rabbit. eats );
```

Comment: Могу ошибаться (тогда пусть меня поправят), но, вроде бы, так происходит из-за того, что изменения прототипа не влияют на уже существующие инстансы.

Comment: @smellyshovel, не изменения прототипа, а полная замена, когда происходит именно _присваивание другого объекта_

Comment: @Grundy да, именно так. Что вполне логично.

Comment: @Grundy, то есть, получается дабы всё функционировало, как я изначально думал (переопределяло прототип на пустой объект), необходимо не присваивать прототипу какой-то другой объект, а в имеющемся объекте прототипа через for in и delete, к примеру поудалять все свойства и методы?

Comment: @barring, в принципе да, но обычно такое не нужно. Какую задачу ты хочешь решить таким образом?

Comment: @Grundy, никакую, просто пытался сделать так, дабы код из примера заработал так, как я думал он должен работать изначально) спасибо за объяснение, а то как - то момент с невозможностью переопределения объекта прототипа я пропустил в ходе чтения материала.

Comment: @barring, переопределить объект прототипа можно, и если бы ты создал объект после присвоения прототипа, то можно было бы увидеть, что применился именно новый прототип. Просто на уже существующих объектах не отразилось бы :)